# Is this possible to tag latest to multiple images in docker?

Tags: docker

I have two images say "Image1" and "Image2". Now, i want to tag these two images to "latest" and then push these to images to my Docker hub public repo.

`docker tag -f $OpImage namespace/reponame:latest`

`docker tag -f $obccaImage namespace/reponame:latest`

and then

`docker push namespace/reponame:latest`

every time in docker hub i could see only one latest tag. Please help me. How to achieve this? Thanks!!

Comment: I think it's `repo_name/image_name:latest`, and you cannot have two images with the same name.

Comment: Is this the command for docker tag or Docker push? My docker hub repo name is xyz/abc-peer and image name as "image1".. So, how to give tag this?

Comment: Yes you can. As long as the images' names are different you can tag them with the same ":tag".

Answer (score 2):

```
$ docker tag --help

Usage:  docker tag [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG] [REGISTRYHOST/][USERNAME/]NAME[:TAG]

$ docker push --help

Usage:  docker push [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG]
```

For example, if your image is `image1`, and docker repo is `xyz/abc-peer`, then you should use

```
docker tag image1 xyz/abc-peer:latest
docker login --username=xyz --email=youremail@company.com
docker push xyz/abc-peer:latest
```

If you have multiple version of the same image, you can tag them with different tags (i.e. xyz/abc-peer:v6, xyz/abc-peer:v7, etc), but you can only have one `latest` in each repo. If you have two different images, they should be put in different repos.

Comment: Docker push abc-peer:latest is giving me unauthorized access but i think i have to give `docker push xyz/abc-peer:latest`. Is that correct?

Comment: Edit my answer to add login and push details